# How to insert new_class style on php echo?

Tags: php, html, class, echo

So it works correctly, but in a style class only

```html
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false).' em até '.$vezes.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getPrice()/$vezes, true, false).' sem juros';?>
```

How to insert new_class style on php echo ?

```
<span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
    <?php $vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');?>
    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false).<div class="new_class">' em até '.$vezes.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getPrice()/$vezes, true, false).' sem juros'</class>
                    ;?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quotes are all over the place, try this:

```
<span class="price" id="old-price-<?php echo $_id ?><?php echo $this->getIdSuffix() ?>">
    <?php $vezes = $_product->getData('parcelas');?>
    <?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_regularPrice, false).'<div class="new_class"> em até '.$vezes.'x de '.$_coreHelper->currency($_product->getPrice()/$vezes, true, false).' sem juros</class>';?>
```

Specifically I changed this:

```
.<div class="new_class">' em até '
```

To this:

```
.'<div class="new_class"> em até '
```

And this:

```
.' sem juros'</class>
```

To this:

```
.' sem juros</div>'
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not listening... tks

Comment: And the </class> should probably be </div>